# What is the difference between Socket/ServerSocket?

Tags: android, serversocket

Recently I'm working on developing an android app which has a part of sharing (only one way) image through Wi-Fi. 
I can create Wifip2pmanager in both device but can't share image till now.
I'm little bit confused on which device I use socket and on which device I use socket server. 
I tried both combination, but it says IOException in the Socket area and I tried both default IP and 10.0.2.2 but didn't work.

1. Can anyone figure me out what should I do now?
2. Is there any need to create wifip2p manager to share file?
3. What is the difference between Socket and ServerSocket?

Comment: where is your code? your question in title does not reflect your explanation or am I confused?

Comment: My code is quite big. And I'm not sure which portion of code to share.

Comment: Edited my question. :)

Comment: A socket is a socket , same socket ,no matter you use it in a server app or clicnt app. Client app and server app is just a human definition . A app can act in same time like client and also like server .Client /Server are just abstract definition .